# Conditions on a topological space $X$ so that every infinite subset $Y$ has a limit point in $Y$

Tags: general-topology

We know that if $X$ is a *compact* topological spaces, then every infinite subset of $X$ has a limit point in $X$.

I'd like to know in what kind of topological space $X$ does each infinite subset $Y$ have a limit point in $Y$.

Comment: The short answer is that $X$ has this property if and only if it has no infinite Hausdorff subspace, but that’s not a very satisfactory answer: it’s barely more than a restatement of the requirement.

Comment: [This](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/217720/an-infinite-set-in-a-compact-space) new MO question seems to be a functional counterpart of yours.